# Unable to install XML package for R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xml, r, ubuntu

I am unable to install XML package on R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) (see the error below). I searched online and I have also installed xml2-dev. It is installed but R cannot find it the library!!

```
[.....]
* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... /data/vision/polina/shared_software/install/gcc-4.3.4/bin/gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... rm: cannot remove `a.out.dSYM': Is a directory
a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /data/vision/polina/shared_software/install/gcc-4.3.4/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /data/vision/polina/shared_software/install/gcc-4.3.4/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /data/vision/polina/shared_software/install/gcc-4.3.4/bin/gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/k/kayhan/home_NFS/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/xml2-config
USE_XML2 = yes
SED_EXTENDED_ARG: -E
Minor 7, Patch 8 for 2.7.8
Located parser file -I/afs/csail.mit.edu/u/k/kayhan/home_NFS/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/libxml2/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  -I/afs/csail.mit.edu/u/k/kayhan/home_NFS/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/libxml2
Using libxml2.*
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
configure: error: "libxml not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/data/vision/polina/users/kayhan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/XML’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI2GiRG/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
```

As I mentioned earlier, I have installed the xml2:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev

kayhan@lemongrass:~$ locate libxml2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
```

the "r-cran-xml" in the repository is not useful b/c it was build before R 3.0. Any idea how to install XML? It is very essential package many other packages depends on it.

Thanks,

Kayhan

Comment: You should post your update as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the my Python Enthought setting has a conflict !! Probaly because it overloads some libraries (by modifying LD_LIRARY). In the .bashrc, I commented out :

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /[....]/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

and installed it and it works! Strange conflict!